# How to replace specific XML node value with WIX during install

Tags: xml, wix

I'm creating an installation package for a service using the WIX Toolset. The installation package is working for simple xml replace but I'm unable to replace values where I have multiple nodes with the "same" path. Example xml config:

```
<service name="service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1234/service1" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
<service name="service2">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1234/service2/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
```

Is there a simple way to replace "1234", during install, in all of the nodes using WIX (1234 is unique in the xml file)? If so, how?

If not, how can i target a specific service node? My guess is the ElementPath? I have a property [newPortValue] which contains the correct value.

```
<Component Id="xmlReplacerForService2" Guid="...">
    <util:XmlFile
    Id="xmlReplacerForService2"
    Action="setValue"
    File="[TESTFILEPRODUCTDIR]service.exe.config"
    SelectionLanguage="XPath"
    Permanent="yes"
    ElementPath="/service?WhatToAdd?"
    Name="baseAddress"
    Value="net.tcp://localhost:[newPortValue]/service2" />
</Component>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the below code and see if that works? (I am not able to test this right now, thats why.) You will have to have multiple util:XmlFile elements for each of the service entries.

```
<util:XmlFile
        Id="xmlReplacerForService2"
        Action="setValue"
        File="[TESTFILEPRODUCTDIR]service.exe.config"
        SelectionLanguage="XPath"
        Permanent="yes"
        ElementPath="/service[\[]@name='service1'[\]]/host/baseAddresses/add"
        Name="baseAddress"
        Value="net.tcp://localhost:[newPortValue]/service2" />
```